# Swift How to do when select map pin and show detail on tableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, mapkit

**I'm new in swift developer and I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.**

**I would like to do when I select the map pin that will show detail on tableView Cell.**

Like this two photo

> This is photo1

[image]

> and when I select the image will like photo2. Name,Address,TelNumber Label will show the Detail

[image]

> and I try to do this code but still didn't work

```
var dictRow = [String:String]()
var dicRow = [String:[String:String]]()
func getAddPin (){
        for index in arrTable{
            let Annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            let bLatitude = index["Latitude"] as! Double
            let bLongitude = index["Longitude"] as! Double
            Annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(bLatitude , bLongitude)
            Annotation.title = index["Name"] as? String
            //writeing detail which pins is already make in map view 
            //I try use Annotation for key when I select pin can get value 
            PinName = [Annotation.title!]               //Name for key      
            dictRow["ClassType"] = index["ClassType"] as? String 
            dicRow[Annotation.title!] = dictRow        //write to dict           
            dictRow["City"] = index["City"] as? String
            dicRow[Annotation.title!] = dictRow
            dictRow["Area"] = index["Area"] as? String
            dicRow[Annotation.title!] = dictRow
            dictRow["Address"] = index["Address"] as? String
            dicRow[Annotation.title!] = dictRow
            dictRow["TelArea"] = index["TelArea"] as? String
            dicRow[Annotation.title!] = dictRow
            dictRow["Tel"] = index["Tel"] as? String
            dicRow[Annotation.title!] = dictRow
            myMapView.addAnnotations([Annotat
}
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        Pintouch = true
        tableView2.isHidden = false
        print(Pintouch)
        myMapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 215, width: DeviceWidth, height: DeviceHeight - 330)
        self.tableView2.reloadData()
      } 
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        Pintouch = false
        tableView2.isHidden = true
        myMapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 35, width: DeviceWidth, height: DeviceHeight - 150)
    }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)-> UITableViewCell {
        if  Pintouch == true {
            cell = tableView2.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! ClintTableViewCell
            MapPinName = PinName[indexPath.item]
            dictRow = dicRow[MapPinName]!
            cell.MyCellName.text = MapPinName
            cell.MyCellCT.text = dictRow["ClassType"]
            cell.MyCellCIty.text = dictRow["City"]
            cell.MyCellArea.text = dictRow["Area"]
            cell.MyCellAddress.text = dictRow["Address"]
            cell.MyCellTelArea.text = dictRow["TelArea"]
            cell.MyCellTelArea.text = cell.MyCellTelArea.text! + "-"
            cell.MyCellTelNum.text = dictRow["Tel"]
}
```

How can I do that? any ideas? cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to create a tableview cell xib and its class then you need to use this method to load that tableview cell xib -

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
        let searchResultDict:SearchResult = self.searchListItems.object(at: index) as! SearchResult
        let DetailScreenVC = DetailScreenVC(nibName: "DetailScreenVC", bundle: nil)
        ScreenVC.organizationId = searchResultDict.organizationId
       ScreenVC.countryId = searchResultDict.countryId
        DetailScreenVC.stateId = searchResultDict.stateId
       DetailScreenVC.activityId = searchResultDict.activityId
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(DetailScreenVC, animated: true)
    }

 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self,options: nil)?.first! as! CustomInfoWindow
      infoWindow.label.text = "\(marker.position.latitude) \(marker.position.longitude)"
    return infoWindow
}
```

PS:- **DetailScreenVC** is your tableview cell nib name

Comment: thanks for answer mate!!! But I didn't use Google Map SKD...so do you have another way can fix this problem?

Comment: You can use MKmap delegate method instead of this -      (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{}   and                                                                                                              - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{}

Comment: Ps:- convert into swift